# Swift Dictionary UIPickerView (key) and (value) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, pickerview

I'm currently developing an app using Swift where I use a UIPickerView. I want to set the value in the pickerView (myPickerView)

```
let PickerData = {
"listOfGrouoc": {
    "1": "DDDDD",
    "2": "SDDDDD",
    "3": "TTTT"
},
"TypeOfGrpos": [
    "STTTTT",
    "TTTTT"
],
"SubTypp": {
    "3": "Shh",
    "6": "SSS",
    "9": " dfdf"
    "14": "Shh",
    "21": "SSS",
    "60": " dfdf"
},
"GropName": {
    "1": "test",
     "2": "test"
    }
  }
```

Here is response comes from server i want to show group listOfGrouoc in pickerView

Code Below:-

In `viewDidLoad` I have:

```
Picker.delegate = self
Picker.dataSource = self
```

Then I have required methods:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return PickerData.count
        }

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return PickerData[row] trying to show SSSSS,DDDDD,GGGGG
        }

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       print(PickerData[row]) expecting only id Int Value
    }
```

Question:- Can someone please explain to me how to set dict value in picker view title and when click on didSelectRow get dict key . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what part of your data you are trying to display in the picker and what value are you expecting to be able to get on didSelectRow?

Comment: @elliott-io Please check i trying to show only name and when select name get Int value.

Comment: Cool. I posted an answer that works.

Comment: @elliott-io okay i will check and update you. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your data, I create new object name **CustomObject** and parse data which will be show in picker to it.

Here is my code:

```
struct CustomObject {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    let PickerData: [String : Any] = ["listOfGrouoc": ["1": "DDDDD","2": "SDDDDD","3": "TTTT"],"TypeOfGrpos": ["STTTTT","TTTTT"],"SubTypp": ["333": "Shh","334": "SSS","543": " dfdf"],"GropName": ["1": "test","2": "test"]]
    var listOfGrouoc: [CustomObject] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 300, height: 200))
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(picker)

        if let list = PickerData["listOfGrouoc"] as? [String: String] {
            for objectID in list.keys {
                if let name = list[objectID] {
                    self.listOfGrouoc.append(CustomObject(id: objectID, name: name))
                }
            }
        }
        //Sort here
        self.listOfGrouoc.sort(by: { $0.id < $1.id})
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfGrouoc.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return listOfGrouoc[row].name
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(listOfGrouoc[row].id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Traj, is there any option to sort this array according to key value. because i getting the randomly array but i want to sort lower to higher

Comment: @ShamDhiman plz check my update in viewDidLoad. Bcz it is characteristic of Dictionary, so after generate to array, we need sort it again as your expected.

Comment: @traj thank you for your reply, i already trying this but it's not working for me

Comment: @traj i want to sort only subtype parameter like 3,6,9 when i sort this they return me 14,9,3,6 i don't know why, its not working for me any solution ?

Comment: @ShamDhiman do the same as `listOfGrouoc` ,  create another object and parse to it, after this just sort again. Show me what you tried to sort SubTypp

Comment: @Traj, please check this screen shot, here is the result got from the server and after sorting this, if I am wrong, please let me the correct way how to sort less to high means 3 to 60. Please let me know the your point. Thank you, Link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LlcQ.png